# @ViewChild returns undefined - Angular 2

Tags: angular, dom, viewchild

I'm trying to use @ViewChild to get the DOM element that I need. I have the following component that describes my problem:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit, Input} from "@angular/core";


@Component({
  selector: 'some-comp',
  template: `

  <input
    #myInputOut
    type="text"
    class="google-place-input"
    placeholder="Type to search..">

   <span class="row form-group">
     <required-input
       class="col-12 has-danger"
       [label]="'somel:'"
       [controlName]="'somel'"
       [form]="group"
      </required-input>
    </span>

 <div class="row form-group2 required">
    <label class=" col-3 control-label" for="street">label:</label>
    <input #myInputIn class="col-7" id="someid" placeholder="Type to search.." /></div>
`
})
export class someClass implements OnInit{

  @ViewChild('myInputOut') myInputOut: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('myInputIn') myInputIn: ElementRef;


  private element: HTMLInputElement;
  private element2: HTMLInputElement;

    constructor(  private databaseService : DatabaseService,
               private router : Router){

  }


  ngOnInit(){
    this.element = this.myInputOut.nativeElement;
    this.element2 = this.myInputIn.nativeElement;
  }
}
```

For some reason `myInputOut` returns properly but `myInputIn` returns undefined.
How can I solve this?

Comment: try to remove comment opening `<!--` before `<div class="row form-group2 required">`

Comment: you are not closing `required-input` correctly .. try to close it

Comment: @Andriy That was the problem, thanks.

Comment: Please make sure the code that you post here is well formatted and syntactically right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are commenting the input or at least started to

```
 <!--  <div class="row form-group2 required">
    <label class=" col-3 control-label" for="street">label:</label>
    <input #myInputIn class="col-7" id="someid" placeholder="Type to search.." />
```

"<!--" shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to access ViewChild queries only inside ngAfterViewInit().
It's not available in ngOnInit() hence you are getting undefined.

Comment: > View queries are set before the ngAfterViewInit callback is called. : https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in the code, kindly fix it and try again.

```
<required-input
   class="col-12 has-danger"
   [label]="'somel:'"
   [controlName]="'somel'"
   [form]="group"
```

there should be a closing tag --> [form]="group" >

```
<!--<div class="row form-group2 required">
```

Remove "`<!--`" before the `<div class="row form-group2 required">` and close it properly with `</div>`

Finally, declare input type `type="text"`

```
<input #myInputIn type="text" class="col-7" id="someid" placeholder="Type to search.." />
```